# Tiles 2 Wildcard to remove duplicate not working

Tags: java, spring, struts2, tiles2, wildcard-mapping

I'm using Spring, Struts 2,  and Tiles 2 in my project and I'm trying to use wildcard notation here to remove the duplicate in my setup from here

```xml
<definition name="home-template1" template="/WEB-INF/jsp/templates/template1.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="banner" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/sitePages/banner.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/sitePages/header.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/sitePages/body.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="archive" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/sitePages/archive.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/sitePages/footer.jsp" />
</definition>
<definition name="home-template2" template="/WEB-INF/jsp/templates/template2.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="banner" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/sitePages/banner.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/sitePages/header.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/sitePages/body.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="archive" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/sitePages/archive.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/sitePages/footer.jsp" />
</definition>
<definition name="home-template3" template="/WEB-INF/jsp/templates/template3.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="banner" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/sitePages/banner.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/sitePages/header.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/sitePages/body.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="archive" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/sitePages/archive.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/sitePages/footer.jsp" />
</definition>
```

to

```xml
<definition name="home-*" template="/WEB-INF/jsp/templates/{1}.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="banner" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/sitePages/banner.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/sitePages/header.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/sitePages/body.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="archive" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/sitePages/archive.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/sitePages/footer.jsp" />
</definition>
```

but tiles gives me the following error:

`org.apache.tiles.definition.NoSuchDefinitionException: home-template2`

below is my `struts.xml` file snipped with only the two action responsible for calling it

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC 
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.1//EN" 
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.1.dtd">
<struts>
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
<constant name="struts.enable.SlashesInActionNames" value="true"/>
<constant name="struts.mapper.alwaysSelectFullNamespace" value="false"/>    
<constant name="struts.action.extension" value=","/> 

<package name="test" extends="struts-default" namespace="/">
    
    <result-types>
        <result-type name="tiles" class="org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult" />
    </result-types>
    
    <action name="checkBlogUrl" class="checkBlogUrl">
        <result name="success" type="redirectAction">
            <param name="actionName">postPreview</param>
            <param name="nextAction">${nextAction}</param>
            <param name="blogSiteUrl">${blogSiteUrl}</param>
        </result>
        <result name="error">/WEB-INF/jsp/cmsPages/index.jsp</result>
    </action>
    
    <action name="postPreview" class="blogPostAction">
        <result name="success" type="tiles">${nextAction}</result>
    </action>
    
</package>
</struts>
```

sample URL call:

```xml
mycms:8080/CMS/postPreview?nextAction=home-template2&blogSiteUrl=qsdcza
```

(Note: I removed the extension `.action/.do` of Struts)

also, can I use the wildcards in the extension? eg:

```xml
<definition name="about-*" extends="home-*">
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/sitePages/about.jsp" />
</definition>
```

want to it myself try but can't make the basic wildcard work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Tiles has wildcard support](https://tiles.apache.org/2.2/framework/tutorial/advanced/wildcard.html) in versions 2.1, 2.2.

> By default, Tiles 2.2 supports wildcards in definition names. Wildcards help a lot in writing less code to declare your definitions.

For better usage of Tiles and Struts2 see [Tiles 2.2.2 Integration](http://struts2.myxwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Struts2/Tiles+2.2.2+Integration).

You can use tiles definition like this

```xml
<definition name="home*" template="/WEB-INF/jsp/templates/{1}.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="banner" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/sitePages/banner.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/sitePages/header.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/sitePages/body.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="archive" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/sitePages/archive.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/sitePages/footer.jsp" />
</definition>
```

Comment: thanks, found my issue. i'm currently using tiles 2.0. Tried to update to 2.2 but I'm having a lot of issue with my pom.